# Why do we get a null point in potentiometer or meter bridge?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

Why do we get a null point in potentiometer or meter bridge. I mean the battery is connected so current should keep flowing through the circuit. So why do we get a point where no current is flowing as the battery is connected

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever made an irrigation canal? Or have you ever tried making rivers in the beach, from the seawater? Then you probably know that water doesn't flow between two points of the same height even if there is water flowing through the river. Similarly, even though current is flowing through both the arms of the circuit of a  wheatstone bridge, the wire connecting their midpoints are like a irrigation canal between two same heights (they have the same electric potential, that's why they are called equipotential points). So current won't flow through them.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a potential difference across a resistor a current will flow through it but if the potential difference is zero then no current flows.

A metre bridge is essentially two potential divider circuits which are connected together as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

Resistors $R_1$ and $R_2$ determine the potential of node $A$, $V_{\rm A}$ and resistors $R_3$ and $R_4$ determine the potential of node $B$, $V_{\rm B}$.

If $V_{\rm A} = V_{\rm B}$ then the potential difference between nodes $A$ and $B$ is zero and thus no current will flow through a resistor (galvanometer) connected between nodes $A$ and $B$ which is called the balanced condition.

In a potentiometer resistor $R_3$ is absent and resistor $R_4$ is replaced by a cell.
The potential $V_{\rm B}$ is determined by the emf of the cell.